# In selector can not use class.property notation

Tags: angular, typescript

test.ts

```
import { OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import { Model } from './model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test'
})

export class Test {
  constructor(
    public  model: Model
  ) { }
}
```

Model class model.ts

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

export class Model {
    @Input() title: string;
}
```

Template (*.html) which has selector

```
<app-test model.title="some text"></app-test>
```

I am not allowed to use **model.title** notation.

How to use class.property notation on selector properties?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `[]` to bind value to input parameter

```
<app-test [title]="model.title"></app-test>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind `@Input` properties' property via `.` notation. You can bind only properties of that component, not nested properties.

You can bind `model` property with an object, which contains the correct structure.

```
<app-test [model]="{title: some text}"></app-test>
```